# Is JPA/Hibernate better with Reverse Engineering or Forward Engineering

Tags: hibernate, reverse-engineering

If we use JPA/Hibernate in a project, Is there any advantage that we can get Generate the Entity class from the DB?, As I have experience there lot of rework if we follow that way and we can't get the advantage of JPA/Hibernate, There are lot of in build functionalities that we can use if. So could anyone tell me pros and cons doing forward Engineering and revers Engineering When we use JPA/Hibernate? My personal opinion is that if we use JPA/Hibernate we should use forward Engineering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well there is also "middle out" design which is by far the best option *when there is an option*.  Forward and reverse engineering come into play when there is not an option; when you have an already existing relational or domain model.  "middle out" design builds both the relational and domain models simultaneously recognizing that together they have synergies as well as hinderances to each other, all of which is best addressed together.

That being said, performing reverse engineering from a well defined relational model is typically not a huge obstacle.  Where this starts to break down (and where you tend to see a lot of "rework") is in cases where the relational model is poorly designed (imho).

Comment: Thank you steve,yes I can agree with you, yes relational model is poorly designed could be one reason, As I feel there are more disadvantages doing reverse Engineering with jpa/hibernate, It's really effect readability(Creates constructor with all fields,Annotation mappings are on the method) of entities as well as difficult to modify,I have noticed there are some missing options in generated classes(Ex: there is no "cascadeType"),correct me if I'm wrong Thank you

Comment: Since you mentioned it specifically... how would any reverse engineering tool be able to ascertain cascade type based on database metadata?  And as far as constructors, it also creates the no-arg forms as well; if you don't like certain constructor forms, just dont use them, simple as that.

Comment: yes Steve,we can stay away from those constructors.Revers Engineering tool couldn't understand cascadeType meta data, I was not clear about that before.Thank you for helping me figure out that, What is you personal suggestion if we develop a system from the beginning, As I think it always better to create DB from entity classes. Thank again for your response

Comment: I have already said that.  Work "middle out".  Develop your domain/logical model; (I think objects work great for this at a conceptual level.  Just be aware that this is best done as an iterative process..